# Job scheduling - how to choose the best one for springMVC based application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I am planning to go for Job scheduling for my spring MVC application and while I was searching for the same I came across [this](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). but really don't have idea whether there are many like `Quartz` or which is the best scheduling API for Spring based application.

Answer (score 3):

I think it really depends upon your requirements. For example:

- Do jobs need to survive a restart of your infrastructure?
- How critical is the availability of the scheduling framework?
- How complex is the type of job you're trying to execute?

Quartz is a dedicated Job scheduling framework and as you would expect comes with many 'enterprisey' features that allow you to build a very highly available, highly performant Job scheduling implementation. It is fairly easy to get started with as well.

Other alternatives could be something like [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) with again provides a very highly available job queue that operates as a service. However the clue is in the name in terms of 'simple'. You loose a lot of the features that something like Quartz would offer. Amazon do however provide a Java wrapper onto the SQS API so managing it as part of your build should be simple enough.

Alternatively the JDK comes with its own built in options. Take a look at the various implementations of the  [java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface. Again depending upon your requirements there may be something in there that fits the bill without having to depend upon external libraries or APIs.

There is also this [list of open-source job scheduling frameworks](http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers) that should help you to compare other offerings with Quartz.